# aspect ratio is changed using ffmpeg sameq and codec copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

i am using ffmpeg to extract clip from mp4 video,

i tried with "-acodec copy -vcodec copy"  and "-sameq"

in both, aspect ration of generated file is changed.

(
     ffmpeg -sameq -i "input file" "output file"

```
 ffmpeg -i "input file" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "outputfile"
```

)

source file is of aspect ratio
sar=4:3
dar=4:3

new file is has aspect ratio
sar=4:3
dar=1:1

please help me to solve this problem,

one weird thing is when i see details in another video tool, it shows me
sar=4:3
dar=4:3
of source video

but when i use command ffmpeg -i sourcefile, it shows me
sar=300:400
dar=1:1

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this command line option is the solution:

```
-aspect aspect      set aspect ratio (4:3, 16:9 or 1.3333, 1.7777)
```

Comment: thanks mike, actually ffmpeg will not identify exact aspect ratio, so i have used mediainfo to get aspect ratio of file and add -aspect as parameter in ffmpeg command

Comment: thanks mike, i have used mediainfo to get the aspect ratio (as file comes dynamically) and then use -aspect in parameter

Comment: Thanks! Yes this works regardless somebody said that need only to re-encode.